# Product by category id in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection

how we can get product by category from collection

Answer (score 0):

To get products by category ID:

```
    $_categoryId=YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_GOES_HERE;

    $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId)
     ->getProductCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

 zend_debug::dump($_products->getData());
```